# Trying to figure out the hashtype of this digest-auth htpasswd file

Tags: authentication, passwords, hash, identity

Simple question for y'all as i'm having some trouble
identifying the hash type of this from a http digest file that
I have setup for rutorrent on a apache2 server.

Here's an example of what it looks like:

```
user:rutorrent:*MD5-HASH*
```

The first two are in plain text while the password
is entirely hashed...and not knowing what kind of
hashing was used on this, I did some research but
haven't found any concrete answers as to what this
is. Seeing it's in the form of a HA1 (Part of the process
of Auth Digest), that's my only clue as to what it is...but
i'm unaware of what kind of hash the password is.

I used john-the-ripper to determine and see what kind of hash-type
it is but that didn't work out.

This hash was generated by rutorrent (I believe) and is placed in
the file named "htpasswd" from "/etc/apache2". Maybe some of y'all
might know what it may be? Please do help me if you can...I'm stuck on
figuring out what this could be heh.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: To see how secure and strong this hash-type is as I learned a variety of different hash-types, how strong they are against cracking and more.

With this one, I never seen such a hash-type before until now and thought someone on here might know what it is.

Comment: http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/htpasswd/

Comment: So about that link (thanks for helping btw), I already know what encryption that is as it's the apache2 "$apr1" but the one i'm asking about is different and I've already given an example of what it looks like.

It's in this format:
`username:realm:hashed-password`

Both username and realm are in plain-text, but for some reason the password is hashed in some MD5 encryption and I believe it's created by rutorrent.

If you want, I can send you an actual sample privately (for security reasons) of what it looks like. Anyways thanks for helping, if anyone knows what this could be...please reply!

Answer (score 1):

32-hex hashes are impossible to indirectly verify, programatically or heuristically. The only way to verify is directly - by actually cracking at least one.

For future searchers, according to [this Arch Linux page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RTorrent/RuTorrent), ruTorrent password hashes are straight MD5, and not some kind of nested/truncated/salted variant:

```
$ echo -n "tom:rtorrent:secret_pass" | md5sum | cut -b -32
6a4aaa1091eb2d1d025bbd692dee3f0c
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what a "http digest file" is. If you mean a password validation database created with htaccess, then the format of the hashed password entries is [very well documented](https://sarata.com/manpages/crypt.3.html), and is very unlikely to use a md5 function directly (it may use smd5). The point of hashing a password is to make it hard to recover the plaintext.